# ReCAPTCHA is stuck on disabled verify after clicking verify

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha, react-google-recaptcha

[My recaptcha on my web app is stuck like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdTc1.png)
I m using **react-google-recaptcha** package

I did not know what you try. I expect it to move to next part of my code

[This is the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3Wvy.png)

Here is a part of  code:

```js
// what code is returning
            <ReCAPTCHA
                sitekey={RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY}
                size="invisible"
                ref={recaptchaRef}
            />

//Handle submit
async function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        const key = await recaptchaRef.current.executeAsync()
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the recaptcha after having use `executeAsync`.

```
    async function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        const key = await recaptchaRef.current.executeAsync()
        recaptchaRef.current.reset()
```

See this github issue for more information : https://github.com/dozoisch/react-google-recaptcha/issues/191#issuecomment-1634072885